# Is there an alternative to a nested query call in Google Sheets?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I've written these queries but I think I might have found a bug in Google Sheets:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(QUERY({Sheet1!$A$2:$E},"select Col2, sum(Col4) where Col5 is null group by Col2 label sum(Col4) ''"), "Select Col1"))
```

The other one is the same, with a different column:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(QUERY({Sheet1!$A$2:$E},"select sum(Col4) where Col5 is null group by Col2 label sum(Col4) ''"), "Select Col1"))
```

Removing the X's in column E shows the query data in F:G, but deleting the X's keeps one of the values. Here is a [live example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JfHNbkiO7if-Mt-5b671gDXFrpFd-aEpIrS8F-kYlaE/edit#gid=49667122).
[image]

The bug goes away if I move the columns around or if I delete the G column or if I delete the label hack.

Unfortunately, although this example appears contrived, it comes from a more complex spreadsheet that I can't modify so easily, so I'm stuck with the column/row arrangement.

Assuming this is a bug that the Google Sheets team should fix (probably caused by the `label sum(Col4) ''` hack), is there any other way to do this?

- Given a table with multiple products, quantities and invoice states

  - get the rows that have not been invoiced (this may be 0 because they're all invoiced or it might be 0 because there are no products, hence the `IFERROR` call and the `label sum(Col4) ''` hack)

    - put the products array (from the filtered rows) in a specific cell (hence the second query call)
    - do the same with the quantities

### Edit after MattKing's and player0's suggestions

Here is the expected state when nothing is invoiced (see [live example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JfHNbkiO7if-Mt-5b671gDXFrpFd-aEpIrS8F-kYlaE/edit#gid=49667122))

[image]

However, this is what happens (some of the time, since I've noticed that the bug comes and goes) when I make all items invoiced:

[image]

Notice that the value in cell F7 is a literal 'p3' leftover from the QUERY. This shouldn't be there, which makes me think it's a Google Sheets bug

Comment: You might need to use the third [optional] parameter of the query function.  if you don't, the function will "guess" which rows are "header" rows and should be excluded, and which are real value rows, and should be included.   Since you have a nested query, it's not entirely clear what you're going for, but try using 0 for both query()'s 3rd parameters.

Comment: Please show your _hand-entered_ expected results from the sample data in your sample spreadsheet.

Comment: @MattKing I changed it to -1 (with 0 it gets added a row below) in both and that seems to fix it 

Comment: @MattKing I tried your suggestion which fixes my attempt, but not yours  See update in the OP

Comment: sorry, i can't visualize what's going on from the screenshots.  to see it here to help. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17oTLatoRWvv7SFKI5EEJq7hOaobYpdK4RmDS70Tbi4Y/

Comment: @MattKing You have the live example here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JfHNbkiO7if-Mt-5b671gDXFrpFd-aEpIrS8F-kYlaE/edit#gid=49667122

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(QUERY({Sheet1!A2:E},
 "select Col2,sum(Col4) where Col5 is not null group by Col2"), 
 "offset 1", 0))
```

### update:

the empty row on top is a residue of including blank rows. to counter that you can use:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(QUERY({Sheet1!$A$2:$E},
 "select Col2, sum(Col4) where Col5 is null and Col4 is not null group by Col2"), 
 "select Col1 offset 1", 0))
```

[image]

or even:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(QUERY({Sheet1!$A$2:$E},
 "select Col2, sum(Col4) where Col5 is null and Col4 is not null group by Col2 label sum(Col4)''"), 
 "select Col1", 0))
```

or shorter:

```
=IFNA(INDEX(QUERY({Sheet1!A$2:E},
 "select Col2,sum(Col4) where Col5 is null and Col4 is not null group by Col2 label sum(Col4)''"),,1))
```

---

```
=IFNA(QUERY({Sheet1!A$2:E},
 "select sum(Col4) where Col5 is null and Col4 is not null group by Col2 label sum(Col4)''"))
```

Comment: Thanks, this almost works. But it leaves an empty row on top.

Answer (score 0):

> `where Col5 is null`

You are asking `query()` to only include data from rows where column E is blank. All the data rows contain a value in column E, so the results will only include data from rows that are blank. Perhaps you are after `where Col5 is NOT null`?